# who serves after tiebreaker in doubles tennis

Tags: tennis, tie-breaker, serve

In doubles tennis, who serves 1st after a tie breaker set?
I realize who starts the tie break but who serves the first regular game after the tie break?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean which person on the doubles team serves first after the tie break or which doubles team serves first?

Comment: @jamauss The latter question is the only interesting one, as it's a new set, so either player on the serving team can serve.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the rules](http://assets.usta.com/assets/1/15/2013_Friend_At_Court1.PDF), rule 5. Score in Game states:

> **5. SCORE IN A GAME**
>   ...The player/team whose turn it was to serve first in the tie-break game shall
>   be the receiver in the first game of the following set.